# Is the target the source of the difficulty?

Tags: difficulty

After every 2016 blocks, the `target` moves up or down to try and create an average of 10 minutes between blocks.

Up until now, I've believed that it's the `difficulty` that drives this change, as though the difficulty is stored on disk somewhere, and the `target` is calculated from this key metric.

However, the only changes I see being stored on disk and shared between nodes is the `target` (via the `bits` field in the block header). This leads me to believe that the `difficulty` is merely a representation of the changing targets, and it's not the actual source of the target values.

So basically, **am I right in saying that the difficulty is calculated *from* the target, and not the other way around?**

e.g: `bits` -> `target` -> `difficulty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So basically, am I right in saying that the difficulty is calculated from the target, and not the other way around?

That is correct. Difficulty is just a concept introduced to make the target value easy to represent for humans.  It has no meaning internally.